# Converted single-byte characters to multibyte characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, byte, multibyte, cjk

In Oracle, there is a function `TO_MULTI_BYTE()` which converts single-byte characters to their corresponding multibyte characters (half-size characters to full-size characters ).

example: TO_MULTI_BYTE('bcd')->ｂｃｄ

However, SQL Server does not have such a function.

How can I do this character-conversion in SQL Server?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We can cast the value to `NVARCHAR` datatype -> `select cast('abcd' as nvarchar(1000))`. Is that you are looking for?

Comment: no,i want to convert character 1 byte to 2 byte in sql server .In oracle have function To_MULTI_Byte() can do it.

Comment: @ThanhLong, casting a varchar/char (single-byte per character) to nvarchar/nchar (multi-bytes per character) will do what you ask. Why isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unicode string to ascii in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634386/convert-unicode-string-to-ascii-in-sql-server)

Comment: ,when u cast varchar to nvarchar ,byte of character don't change output not yet up to fullsize.example: cast('bcd' as nvarchar(1000) have ouput is 3 byte ,output is bcd.however in oracle to_multi_byte('bcd') will have output is 6 byte.output->ｂｃｄ