# How to Force my C# windows forms to use arabic number?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, cultureinfo

I am trying to force my forms to use arabic format like displaying (1-2-3-4-..,etc) numbers as (٠‎ , ١‎ , ٢‎ , ٣‎ , ٤‎ , ٥‎ , ٦‎ , ٧‎ , ٨‎ , ٩‎) in all areound my forms no matter if it is `Textbox`,or`lables`or whatever it is

I searched and found a lout of question talking about this issue most of them not working and the other I believe are not seems to be good answer like the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298153/how-can-i-convert-english-digits-to-arabic-digits) and as shown below what I have tried on form loading which has no effect on my issue

and here is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926792/converting-numbers-from-western-arabic-digits-1-2-3-to-eastern-arabic-digit) that says that cultureinfo will not help is it right ?? because I do not think that answer is right

so please if someone can help me

```
private void F0102_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ar_culture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ar_culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ar_culture;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most Arabic people use western Arabic numbers (1, 2, 3...) for math. Therefore, even with the `ar-SA` culture you get those when formatting numbers. Use your own formatting function to get eastern Arabic numbers.

```
public static string ToArabic(long num)
{
    const string _arabicDigits = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹";
    return new string(num.ToString().Select(c => _arabicDigits[c - '0']).ToArray());
}
```

You can also create your own format provider:

```
public class ArabicNumberFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public static readonly ArabicNumberFormatProvider Instance =
        new ArabicNumberFormatProvider();

    private ArabicNumberFormatProvider() { }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType) { return this; }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        switch (arg) {
            case long l:
                return ToArabic(l);
            case int i:
                return ToArabic(i);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static string ToArabic(long num)
    {
        const string _arabicDigits = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹";
        return new string(num.ToString().Select(c => _arabicDigits[c - '0']).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Example:

```
string arabic = String.Format(ArabicNumberFormatProvider.Instance,"{0}", 1234567890);
```

Output:

> ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰

However, `num.ToString(ArabicNumberFormatProvider.Instance)` does not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240052/880990 for details.

Comment: I need to call it on each textbox to show the arabic numbers?
and I am getting error `; expected` on that line `public object GetFormat(Type formatType) => this;`  what the advantage of that line please ?  `private ArabicNumberFormatProvider() { }`

Comment: This is C#7 syntax. Changed it to old syntax. `private ArabicNumberFormatProvider() { }` makes the constructor private, so that you have to use `ArabicNumberFormatProvider.Instance` instead of `new ArabicNumberFormatProvider()`. It makes the class a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).